# Is there syntax for a tr line specific CSS selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm studying for a HTML, CSS, JS exam and found various resources to help me study. In doing a practice quiz, I have found a question about a tr line CSS selector:

[image: What the selector should be doing]

[image: This is what the question and options are]

The quiz tells me that option B is correct.

From my research, there is no such thing as a [line |-0,1,3] selector syntax.

I'd like to verify is this syntax is correct, or whether I'm correct in saying that this is an error on the quiz's part.

I've tested this in codepen.io editor which does not work either, this is found here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPwwpB?editors=110

```
tr [line |- 0,1,3] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Lastly if this syntax is not correct, can you also confirm the correct syntax? (HTML excluded from this post for clarity, but available on the Codepen link)

Comment: That syntax is definitely not correct, and your answer seems right...

Comment: "ASAP" sounds like this is not a quiz but a test

Comment: @IkoTikashi as i said in the description, I'm studying for an exam, which is a test yes, it is in a few days time, so I'm just nutting out the things I'm not sure on before I sit it :)

Comment: I googled for the same reason :D

Comment: I encounter this quiz today...I believe C is the right answer. It seems this is extracted from Micro$oft exam for HTML5 and CSS3, so I'm considering whether 'line' selector will work on IE.. just guess

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned, choice C, `tr:first-of-type, tr:last-of-type`, is the correct answer, but only if the rows are semantically divided into a `thead` and a `tbody` element as choice A seems to imply.

Here's an illustration of how each of the desired elements would be matched based on the above assumption:

```css
tr:first-of-type, tr:last-of-type {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Product         <!-- tr:first-of-type, tr:last-of-type -->
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Adjustable Race <!-- tr:first-of-type -->
    <tr><td>Blade
    <tr><td>Chainring
    <tr><td>Down Tube       <!-- tr:last-of-type -->
</table>
```

Assuming the `thead` and `tbody` do not have any other children than `tr` (such as `template` or `script`), `tr:first-child, tr:last-child` would work as well. Note that choice D is incorrect however because it uses the `:first-line` pseudo-element with legacy single-colon syntax, and not the `:first-child` pseudo-class, and furthermore the `:first-line` pseudo-element does not make sense on a table-row element.

Choice B is incorrect, as there is no such syntax. The others make an excellent point in that such syntax does not make sense for a selector, since it appears to use attribute syntax with a non-existent attribute called "lines", followed by garbage masquerading as some sort of operator, followed by invalid value syntax, and on top of all that the entire "attribute selector" is preceded by a descendant combinator even though the selector should be targeting the `tr` elements and not their descendants. And I agree with CBroe's comment in that it might have been put in simply to confuse — though it does make one wonder if the test setter could have deliberately marked it as the correct answer to troll...

Furthermore, tables don't have a notion of "lines"; they have "rows" instead, so it would be extremely careless to call such a selector "line" (although, then again, we have `:link` for unvisited links and `:visited` for visited links, [which has come back to bite us now](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#the-any-link-pseudo)).

You may wonder if there is any special selector syntax for matching table-row elements besides the basic `:*-of-type` pseudo-classes. No, there isn't. This is because HTML is a *row-primary* markup language, which means rows are expressed in the form of row elements (hence `tr`), and columns implied by a series of cell elements. Thus, there is little need to create special selectors to match rows when the basic structural pseudo-classes work just fine for this purpose.

It is not possible to match cells relative to one another based on row semantics however, especially considering that cells can span multiple rows via the `rowspan` attribute. For example, you can't write a selector matching cells in a certain column relative to a certain multi-row cell unless you select the specific rows that that cell appears in, which often requires prior knowledge of the markup and an assumption that that structure will not change. This *may* improve with the [`:has()` pseudo-class](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational) introduced in Selectors 4, but how it will be used in such a scenario, or if it can at all, remains to be seen.

Answer (score 6):

For your specific case, your answer definitely was the right choice, and the `[line |- whatever]` is not correct CSS syntax.

In general, the only correct CSS syntax is `selector:specific-something`, `selector:specific(something)`, or `selector[attr=val]`.  Anything else that looks different probably is wrong (unless you're using a CSS preprocessor).

Answer (score 3):

<del>The HTML on your codepen doesn’t match the question – where is the “Adjustable Race” row/caption/whatever?</del>

That being said, if “Product” is the only `tr` in `thead`, and “Adjustable Race” and “Down Tube” are the first and last `tr` in `tbody`, then answer C should be correct.

`tr [line |- 0,1,3]` doesn’t seem to make any sense whatsoever – even if that *was* meant to be an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors), that `line` attribute would have to be on the `td` elements (because of the space between `tr` and `[`), but there is not such attribute to be seen anywhere in your HTML (and a `line` attribute doesn’t exist in HTML), and `|-` would have to be `|=`.

Comment: Thanks your right, missed the adjustable race row, updated for correctness

Comment: OK, then answer C is the only thing that makes sense here. I’d assume that the person setting up the quiz simply made a mistake here (and marked the wrong answer as the correct one). The `tr [line |- 0,1,3]` answer is probably only in there to confuse, and A and D won’t achieve the result asked for either.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 version of this question answers are

```
 first-of-type,tr-last-of-type
```

or

```
tr:nth-child(3n+1) {background-color: blue;}
```

both of them true